# Is there any way to combine client-side and server-side Google API authentication?

Tags: oauth, google-api

Currently I am implementing an Ionic application that the front-end is on the mobile devices and the back-end is on the server. (So there is a connection latency between the device and the server) And my application is using the Google services (like Gmail, calendar, etc) by connecting to the Google API.

1. Currently the architecture is:

   Device <==> Server <==> Google API

   This is using the OAuth 2.0 server-side authentication. It works but the connection latency is way too long and feels like going back to the time when we have the dial-up internet connection.
2. I tried to use the OAuth 2.0 client-side authentication, which is:

   Device <==> Google API

   This is faster but it has 2 problems:

   1. Even though Ionic packaged the front-end code into an application, I still have concerns that the rule "Everything in the front-end is visible to everyone" stays. (Did not find an evidence to prove or disapprove this hypothesis)
   2. Google API OAuth 2.0 only issues flows to the client-side authentication, and flows expire very often, I don't want the user to grant the permission again and again.

So, I was wondering if it is possible to do the following:

- Use the server-side authentication to store keys/credentials (I'm using Django as the back-end, which is Python) and the front-end gets keys/credentials from the server and proceed Google service using JavaScript codes.

Comment: Anyone can give me an advice? Will appreciate

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late to the party, but I'm going through this now. I think there are 2 ways to set this up, but neither are perfect.

1. Use server-side flow to authorize all the scopes you'll need on either the server or the client. When the token is obtained, pass it to your client. The down side is that the client now has a token that has access to more APIs than needed.
2. Create seperate authorization flows for both the client and server. This would mean the user has 2 authorization prompts, which is no good. The good thing about this approach is you could ensure the client has limited scopes, but the server could still handle the larger tasks (moving Drive files, sending emails, etc.)

In my case, the client would just need read access to the Contacts API, whereas the server needs full Drive access.

If anyone finds a combination approach, where only 1 authorization is needed, but the client and server have seperate scopes, that'd be the ideal situation.